# Fine uploader message error

Tags: yii, widget, fine-uploader

I am using yii framework with fine uploader. When i moved my project on a new server I suddenly got this message error in console:

```
Error: element not found file
throw new Error('element not found ' + type);
```

This is the code why I'm getting the error. But I don't understant what this do(this is from the library fine uploader)

```
_find: function(parent, type){
        var element = qq(parent).getByClass(this._options.classes[type])[0];
        if (!element){
            throw new Error('element not found ' + type);
        }

        return element;
    },
```

this is the php code:

```
    <?php
    $this->widget('ext.fineuploader.EFineUploader', array(
        'id' => 'FineUploader',
        'config' => array(
            'autoUpload' => true,
            'text' => array(
                'uploadButton' => 'Adaugă CV'
            ),
            'request' => array(
                'endpoint' => $this->createUrl("/cariera/uploadTmpFile"),
                'params' => array('YII_CSRF_TOKEN' => Yii::app()->request->csrfToken),
            ),
            'retry' => array('enableAuto' => false, 'preventRetryResponseProperty' => true),
            'chunking' => array('enable' => true, 'partSize' => 100), //bytes
            'callbacks' => array(
                'onComplete' => "js:function(id, name, response){ "
                . "  if(response.success){"
                . "    $('#Candidate_cv_path_em_').hide();"
                . "    $('#Candidate_cv_path').val(response.folder+'/'+name);"
                . "    var width = $('.qq-upload-button > div').width();"
                . "    if($('.qq-upload-button > div.progressBar')){"
                . "          $('.qq-upload-button > div.progressBar').remove();"
                . "    }"
                . "    $('.qq-upload-button').prepend('<div class=\"progressBar\"></div>');"
                . "    $('.qq-upload-button > div.progressBar').animate({width: '150px'}, 1000, function(){ $('.qq-upload-button > div').html('CV atașat'); });"
                . "  }"
                . "}",
                'onError' => "js:function(id, name, errorReason){ $('#Candidate_cv_path_em_').html(errorReason).show();}",
            ),
            'validation' => array(
                'allowedExtensions' => array(),
                'sizeLimit' => 2 * 1024 * 1024, //maximum file size in bytes
                'minSizeLimit' => 1, // minimum file size in bytes
                'acceptFiles' => 'application/pdf, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/msword'
            ),
        )
    ));
    echo "<span class='info_upload'>(.pdf, .doc, .docx)</span>";
//    echo $form->error($applicant, 'cv', array('class' => "errorMessage errorCv"));
//    echo $form->labelEx($applicant, 'cv', array('label' => '<span class="progressBar"></span>Upload CV', 'class' => 'uploadcv'));
//    echo $form->fileField($applicant, 'cv', array('size' => '1', 'class' => 'hiddenInputFile'));
    ?>
```

Can someone help me with this ?

Update:
**I noticed that it is not generated this html part on the new server:**

```
<ul class="qq-upload-list">
<li class=" qq-upload-success">
     <div style="display: none; width: 100%;" class="qq-progress-bar">
    </div>
     <span style="display: none;" class="qq-upload-spinner"></span>
     <span class="qq-upload-finished"></span>
     <span class="qq-upload-file">free_cv_sample_template.pdf</span>
     <span style="display: inline;" class="qq-upload-size">0.1MB</span>
     <a style="display: none;" class="qq-upload-cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
     <a class="qq-upload-retry" href="#">Retry</a>
     <a class="qq-upload-delete" href="#">Delete</a>
     <span class="qq-upload-status-text"></span>
</li>
</ul>
```

**Why ?**

Comment: At what exact point in the code is the error occurring?  Please provide the full stack of the log/error message.  Also, what version of Fine Uploader are you using?

Comment: the version is 3.4.1. What exact point ? I dont know

Comment: You'll need to provide more specific information, or perhaps post on the yii forums.  As it stands, you have posted an error message without any context.  Also, the version of Fine uploader you are using is a couple years old.

Comment: Best guess without knowing anything about the context of your error message or what "ext.fineuploader.EFineUploader" is: you haven't specified an `element` option (?) https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/blob/3.4.1/docs/options-fineuploader.md

Comment: also it is very weird that on my localhost it works and also on the initial server. But on the new one it does not work. Is it possible for some configuration reason it does not work ?

Comment: I am widely open to any new stupid idea.